# Set boolVar to true if all TD has text otherwise set it to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<table id="contenedorFabricantes" style="" class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr class="tableHead">
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="toggleCheckboxFabricantes" id="toggleCheckboxFabricantes"></th>
        <th>Fabricante</th>
        <th>Dirección</th>
        <th>País</th>
        <th>Teléfono</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="fabricanteBody">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        <td>Distribuidor1</td><td>8768 Dewy Apple Wynd, Foxtrap, Montana</td>
        <td id="fabTd-1" class="has_pais"></td>
        <td>4061782946</td>
        <td><a data-backdrop="static" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-toggle="modal" id="1" class="editable-pais" href="#"><i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-original-title="Agregar países"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        <td>Distribuidor1</td><td>8768 Dewy Apple Wynd, Foxtrap, Montana</td>
        <td id="fabTd-1" class="has_pais">Country1, Country2</td>
        <td>4061782946</td>
        <td><a data-backdrop="static" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-toggle="modal" id="1" class="editable-pais" href="#"><i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-original-title="Agregar países"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to set `boolVar` to false if at least one `td.has_pais` has not text meaning `""` and this is what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var boolVar = true,
  hasPaises = $('#fabricanteBody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
      $(this).text() === "" ? boolVar = false : boolVar = true;
  });

  console.log(boolVar);
});
```

But I'm doing something wrong since `boolVar` gets `true` and with provided HTML example should be false, can any tell me where I'm failing?

Comment: You need to preserve state, or you'll end up only with the result of the last matched `td`. Use `&=` or something similar

Comment: @blgt could you provide a solution?

Comment: There is one already, see [adeneo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27174755/2685386). The wrong assignment operator is just a bug in the above

Comment: @blgt can you take a look to the comment on adeneo's answer?

Comment: @blgt I'm testing [here](http://jsbin.com/rijiwamedo/1/edit?html,js,console) but get false all the time, even if all td with `.has_pais` has text

Comment: You need to test it with valid HTLM, you can't have a tbody without a table.

Comment: @adeneo as I said in a previous comment on your answer _Don't worry about the table, my markup is fine on my side this one is an abridged version with only the relevant code, but my logic meaning yours is fine?_ btw I updated the post with the complete table ;)

Comment: Okay, but you can't test it in JSBIN without the table, as the browser will try to change your HTML into something that is valid, and nothing will work like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:empty()` and check the length of the collection

```
var boolVar = $('#fabricanteBody .has_pais:empty').length > 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this code does, it will check for each `td.has_pais` if has text or not and set `boolVar` value to `true` or `false`? So taking the HTML as example in this case ``boolVar` will take `false` right?

Comment: This finds any `.has_pais` elements that are empty. jQuery's `:empty` also works on text nodes, so it will only find elements that has no text. Checking the length tells us if any empty elements where found, if so the length will be more than zero, and it will return `true` if there are empty elements.

Comment: So, [this](http://jsbin.com/rijiwamedo/1/edit?html,js,console) is fine? If at least one `td.has_pais` has no values `boolVar` should be true otherwise will be false, I'm right?

Comment: @ReynierPM - No, that's not fine, you're missing the entire `table` element, so it doesn't work !

Comment: @adeneo Don't worry about the table, my markup is fine on my side this one is an abridged version with only the relevant code, but my logic meaning yours is fine?

Comment: @LShetty: I think you meant `!== 0` which is the same as `!$('#fabricanteBody .has_pais:empty').length`